# I want to find 'import/Export' mistake in eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-typescript

```
#File ./A.ts
const a = 1;
const b = 3;
export {a}
```

```
#File ./B.ts
import {a} from './A'

const B = ()=> {
  const result = a + b;   <== this line error 'b not export '

}
```

I want to find eslint or typescript rules

#test...
eslint --rule 'import/default: error' ./B.ts

I want errors to be detected when building!!!

Comment: OK, go do that and come back with actual questions perhaps.